# How to concatanate html links and display them in div

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In js file i have

```
 vm.text= response.children.map(function (e) {
                                        var html = '<a ng-click="hello">' +  e.number+ '</a>';
                                        return html;
                                    }).join('  ||  ');
```

In html i have

```
 <div>
                  <strong> {{vm.text}}</strong>
            </div>
```

`Above div display <a ng-click="hello">9253</a> ||  <a ng-click="hello">1025</a>`

instead of just numbers w a hyperlink. I am guessing {{}} won't allow html. How do i make it not do it and display links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `<strong [innerHTML]="vm.text"></strong>`.

Edit: I didn't notice the `ng-` prefix, you should use `ng-bind-html` instead.

Comment: didn't work. Does this work for angularJS also or just new angular? mine right now is angularJS

Comment: Could you try with `<strong ng-bind-html="vm.text"></strong>`?

Comment: That worked.Thanks.:) can you update your answer so i can accept it